# How can I get ids of grouped rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
// notifications
+----+--------+-----------+---------+--------------------+
| id | money  | post_id   | user_id | belongs_to_user_id |
+----+--------+-----------+---------+--------------------+
| 1  | 5      | 1         | 123     | 101                |
| 2  | 10     | 2         | 123     | 101                |
| 3  | -2     | 4         | 456     | 101                |
| 5  | -2     | 2         | 456     | 101                |
| 6  | -2     | 3         | 123     | 101                |
| 7  | 5      | 4         | 789     | 101                |
| 8  | 10     | 4         | 789     | 101                |
+----+--------+-----------+---------+--------------------+
```

And here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM notifications
WHERE belongs_to_user_id = 101
GROUP BY post_id, user_id
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 3
```

The **current output** should be something like this:

```
+----+--------+-----------+---------+--------------------+
| 5  | -2     | 2         | 456     | 101                |
| 6  | -2     | 3         | 123     | 101                |
| 8  | 10     | 4         | 789     | 101                |
+----+--------+-----------+---------+--------------------+
```

The seventh row is grouped and we cannot see it in the result. That's exactly the problem. Here is the **expected result**:

```
+----+--------+-----------+---------+--------------------+
| 5  | -2     | 2         | 456     | 101                |
| 6  | -2     | 3         | 123     | 101                |
| 7  | 5      | 4         | 789     | 101                |
| 8  | 10     | 4         | 789     | 101                |
+----+--------+-----------+---------+--------------------+
```

---

If I remove `GROUP BY`, then the fifth will be omitted. So here is the logic:

> I want to the last three rows *(regardless grouping)*. In other word, Emm ... it's hard to say, I want to select grouped rows (but not counting in `LIMIT`).

Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: That group by is invalid. It won't execute on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), may return unpredictable results with older MySQL versions. The general GROUP BY rule says: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!"

Comment: It would be hard to answer if what you want is emm ... hard to say.

Comment: _I want to the last three rows (regardless grouping). In other word, Emm ... it's hard to say, I want to select (bot not counting in LIMIT) grouped rows._

Please help us understand what you want :)

Comment: @KaeL I want to group rows, then limit 3 rows, then make rows ungroup, and return them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try this query. It will get the last three "groups", and then extract all the rows of those groups (using a join):

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM notifications t
 INNER JOIN (SELECT s.post_id, s.user_id
               FROM notifications s
              WHERE belongs_to_user_id = 101
              GROUP BY post_id, user_id
              ORDER BY post_id DESC, user_id DESC
              LIMIT 3) u
    ON u.post_id = t.post_id
   AND u.user_id = t.user_id
 WHERE t.belongs_to_user_id = 101
 ORDER BY t.id
```

**Update:** same query using DISTINCT in the subquery:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM notifications t
 INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT s.post_id, s.user_id
               FROM notifications s
              WHERE belongs_to_user_id = 101
              ORDER BY post_id DESC, user_id DESC
              LIMIT 3) u
    ON u.post_id = t.post_id
   AND u.user_id = t.user_id
 WHERE t.belongs_to_user_id = 101
 ORDER BY t.id
```

Comment: *"It will get the last three "groups", and then extract all the rows of those groups "* ..! I'm happy you understand what I meant.

Comment: Why did you removed the `WHERE` clause in your query?

Comment: @MartinAJ the join already filters the result of the query. You will get only the rows which have last three post_id and user_id

Comment: I'm talking about `WHERE belongs_to_user_id = 101`

Comment: Thank you, just I will ask another query to improve your query (doesn't seems optimal to me, because there are multiple more columns in reality).

Comment: @MartinAJ you're welcome. You could also use a DISTINCT in the subquery, instead of group by. But I think the DB engine already treats them the same way, using the same execution path

Comment: Can you please add the query of your new suggestion? *(using `DISTINCT`)*

Answer (score 11):

It shows comma separated id by groups

```
SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT(id),
  post_id 
 FROM notifications 
 WHERE belongs_to_user_id = 101 
 GROUP BY post_id, user_id
 ORDER BY id DESC 
 LIMIT 3
```

Comment: best one in MySQL rather than writing nested queries

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE belongs_to_user_id = 101 GROUP BY id, money ORDER BY id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you want correlation `subquery` if i am not wrong

```
select * from table t
where belongs_to_user_id = 101 and 
      user_id = (select max(user_id) from table where post_id = t.post_id)
```

Additionally, you could add `limit` clause to limit the records that you want.